# Redirect awk result to text file

Tags: windows, command-line, awk, command-line-arguments, gawk

I have the following lines in a file

```
lines="188"
lines="24"
lines="25"
```

and I extract the values inside the quotation marks (""), and sum up the values to get 237 by using the following commands

```
awk -F'\"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}'
```

However, I want to redirect the output to a text file. I tried using the redirect operation (>) operator, but it keeps giving me the error

This is what I have so far

```
awk -F'\"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}' > "sum.txt"
```

And this is the error

```
fatal: cannot open file '>' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `"I tried using the redirect operation (>) operator"` ***Show*** what you tried.

Comment: did you give the filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited** - It seems there is a problem with quotes being handled in the line between awk and cmd. To use a quote as delimiter change it to

```
awk -F \x22 "{count+=$2}END{print count+0}" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Comment: i think it won't work for him. See the op's comments on my answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, you are right. I did not see the conflict in the quote handling. Corrected

Comment: @MCND, after the edit of `\x22` this worked! Thanks!

Comment: @bacaviteno why don't you give the FS value inside the BEGIN block?

Answer (score 1):

You failed to mention the path of input file-name in your command . Your command should be,

```
awk -F'"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}' inputfile > "sum.txt"
```

And also you don't need to escape FS value `"` inside single quotes.

Comment: It is still giving me the error

    awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=temp.txt FNR=3) fatal: cannot open file `>' for read
ing (No such file or directory)

Comment: awk -F'\"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}' temp.txt > sum.txt

Comment: How it shows ` (FILENAME=temp.txt FNR=3) cannot open file `>' for read ing (No such file or directory)` but your actual command is a different one.

Comment: oops, sorry that was supposed to be temp.txt

Comment: does the temp.txt file presnet in your current directory? Did you add spaces before and after `>`?

Comment: Yes, it is present in the directory, and there are spaces before and after the >

Comment: remove the output redirection operation and the output file. Check now your awk command prints the result or not?

Comment: now create a new file inside same directory. Run this command `awk -F'"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count; else print 0}' infile >> outfile` command to append the output to `outfile` file.

Comment: I have created the new ouputfile and it is still giving an error `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=temp.txt FNR=3) fatal: cannot open file '>>' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: `awk -F'\"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}' temp.txt >> sum.txt`

Comment: now try this, `awk -F'"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count; else print 0}' inputfile | tee outputfile`

Comment: do't forget to create outputfile on the same directory before executing the above command.

Comment: There is still an error `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=temp.txt FNR=3) fatal: cannot open file '|' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: weired, it takes any special characters as file.

Comment: Yes, I wondering why it is treating everything after the command as arguments when there is the `-F'"'`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it some:

```
awk -F\" '{count+=$2}END{print count+0}' file > sum.txt
```

By adding `0`, you get the same as your test, printing `0` also if `count` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Input file is missing.

```
awk -F'\"' '{count+=$2;}END{if(count>0) print count;else print 0}' inputfile > "sum.txt"
```

Quotes for the output file is not a problem.